# Android: Refreshing view from UI thread

Tags: android, scala, android-listview

Basic question, but my attempts to resolve it have failed

My activity contains the following

```
override def onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 setContentView(R.layout.match_list_view)
 val listView = findViewById(R.id.matchListView).asInstanceOf[ListView]
 listView.setAdapter(new MatchListViewAdapter(MatchDao.retrieveAllMatches(), this, listView))
```

}

which displays a list of matches in a ListView

My adapter then contains the following logic in its getView method for an individual match:

```
val deleteButton = updatedView.findViewById(R.id.deleteIndividualMatchButton).asInstanceOf[Button]
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
      override def onClick(v: View) {
        new DeleteMatchDialogFragment(getItem(position), MatchListViewAdapter.this).show(activity.getFragmentManager, "DeleteFragment"
      }
    })
```

My DeleteMatchDialogFragment then contains the following logic:

```
override def onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Dialog = {
    createDialog(null, R.string.deleteMatch, R.string.ok, {
      MatchDao.delete(matchToDelete)
      adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated()
    })
  }
```

So basically in the `ListView`, I have a list of Matches and each one has a Delete button opposite it.
When the user clicks the Delete button I wish to delete the match from the database and then refresh the `ListView`.

Everything is working fine, except that the view is not refreshed.
I also tried adding `view.invalidate()` to the `DeleteMatchDialogFragment` but no luck either.

What do I need to do here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> When the user clicks the Delete button I wish to delete the match from
>   the database and then refresh the ListView

To delete item from ListView create a method `MatchListViewAdapter` which remove item from same instance of data-source which is used in `getCount` method like:

```
public void removeItem(int pos){

  this.dataContainer.remove(pos);
  this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Call `removeItem` item in `createDialog` method before `MatchDao.delete(matchToDelete)`

Comment: This is the correct answer and it works, I downvoted in error when I misinterpreted your answer.

Comment: @DJ180: ok friend but when you down vote then also add comment why you are down voting by which we can improve answer ,remember point for  next time provide answer to other user. Thanks now u can remove down vote if it help thanks

Comment: I added a comment at the time but have since deleted it, but I misinterpreted the answer. I've asked the mods to upvote instead so hopefully they will! Thanks